# No Access to C drive on Windows 7 x64 Home Premium

Tags: windows-7, boot-partition

I'm on a computer whose user (Administrator account) says he changed network sharing settings for C:\ but made a mistake and after that, C: was no longer accessible.

Windows generally starts, some programs such as explorer.exe and cmd.exe can be started, but others such as regedit.exe cannot. Also, many settings dialogs, control panel options etc. are not displayed because "Administrator has restricted access" or "Server cannot be started" or just no message. I can, however, access everything in the C:\Users\ directory (still, the `dir` command in cmd.exe fails even there). I seem to be able to start MMC and add snap-ins.

Drive C:\ is shown without drive name in Windows Explorer. I can open its properties, but can't change the owner of drive C:\ or indeed access any options there at all.

Safe mode and domain controller restore mode don't change any of this as well (which is why [this advice](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/7fe04a5c-2ba8-4490-9f80-ec15a2e2483c/) didn't work either because of regedit and because I can't change the owner.

How can I restore access to drive C:\?

Comment: Sounds like he buggered up the file permissions while trying to set Share permissions, Have you tried a System Restore yet?

Comment: ICacls c: gives what?

Comment: @soandos: `c: NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F)` <newline> `VORDEFINIERT\Administratoren:(OI)(CI)(F)` <newline> `Arbeit-PC\Arbeit:(OI)(CI)(F)` <newline> `Arbeit-PC\HomeUsers:(RX)` <newline> `1 Files successfully processed, at 0 files a processing error occurred.`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why they didn't put it into a full fledged answer but yes, the first place I would go on this would be an attempt at System Restore.

Comment: Because 1/2 the 'answers' would be "Have you tried a System Restore yet?" :)

Comment: It can't find any restore points, not sure if there are none but at some point the program also gave me an "Access denied".

Comment: @techie007 LOL FAIR, WIN - chastised LOL!